# Can a monk use his Martial Arts bonus-action unarmed strike when using a readied action to attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, actions, readied-action

My group is pretty new to D&D 5e, and the bonus action is confusing one of our players.

When a monk does an attack from a readied action, can he then use his bonus-action unarmed strike?

I assume he cannot do the bonus attack because it is only usable on when the Attack action is taken, but his argument is that the readied action is the Attack action so it can be used.

Answer (score 18):

### He can't

During their turn a character can perform:

- one action
- one bonus action
- one reaction

When a player announces Ready action, they don't delay the whole turn, but only the action:

> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose **the action you will take** in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

That means you can't do bonus actions via the Ready action, since you only can perform a bonus action on your turn. Moreover, you spend your *reaction* as well:

> When the trigger occurs, you can either take your reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore the trigger. Remember that you can take only one reaction per round.

See the related question: [How does the Ready action work in D&D 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80796/)

### The feature description clarifies this

The Martial Arts description explicitly says you make the bonus action **on your turn**:

> **Martial Arts**
>   When you use the Attack action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon on your turn, you can make one unarmed strike as a bonus action.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Bonus actions can only ever be taken on your turn.

Comment: @enkryptor Beauty.  Answer covers it all.

Comment: In effect, a readied action is still an action. It sets up an arbitrary condition under which you can take an arbitrary (but pre-selected) action as your *reaction*.

Comment: One can use bonus-action unarmed strike if readied Attack action is triggered on one's turn (e.g. in the same turn he readied an action). P.S. on edit: *they don't delay the whole turn* - "they" is singular in the context, *you can't do bonus actions* - "bonus actions" should be singular because you can't get more than one.

Comment: It may also help to differentiate the **Ready** Action from the **Attack** Aciton.

Answer (score 5):

### He CANNOT make a bonus action!

The Ready action (Sage-Advice Compendium)

> If you want to wait to act in response to something, take the Ready
>   action, which lets you take part of your turn later

Ready Action (PHB pg. 177)

> you can take the Ready action on your turn so that you can
>   act later in the round using your reaction. First, you decide what perceivable circumstance
>   will trigger your reaction.

The *Ready* action allows you to declare a *specific instance*, and *wait for it to happen* in order to use your ***reaction*** later in the round.

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can
>   occur on your turn or on someone else’s.

Because you are taking the *ready action*, you are ***using your turn to wait until someone else's*** turn in order to trigger said reaction. The ready action would not be considered *your turn*, because you used your turn to take the ready action, and you are now waiting until later to use the *action that was prepared on your turn*.

In response to a seperate question in the Sage-Advice Compendium, the answer simply stated:

> No, since **you can’t take a bonus action on someone else’s turn**.

Because the Ready action requires you to wait until someone else's turn, be it enemy, friendly, or even environmental, it is not considered "your turn" and you cannot use a bonus action because of this.

Martial Arts (PHB pg. 72)

> When you use the **Attack** action with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon
>   on **your turn**, you can make one unarmed strike **as a bonus action**.

This states that it must be "**your turn**" to add this bonus action, which you cannot take. Additionally, it also requires you take the ***Attack action in the first place***, which you are not as you are taking the *Ready action to prepare an attack*, which is *not the same as taking the Attack action*.